# Enviar informacion entre clases - Java - JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Mi situacion es la siguiente:
Primero, tengo una clase llamada "Pantalla_MenuPeliculas", que tiene sus etiquetas, botones, etc. En esta misma clase dispongo de un ArrayList de la clase Pelicula.
Segundo, tengo una clase llama "MenuPeliculas_Importar", que tiene sus etiquetas, botones, etc. Yo lo que quiero lograr, es que mediante la clase "MenuPeliculas_Importar", enviar un ArrayList a la clase "Pantalla_MenuPelicula".
A continuacion les dejo el codigo:

// CLASE PANTALLA_MENUPELICULAS -------------------------------------------------------

```
public class Pantalla_MenuPeliculas extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    // ATRIBUTOS
    private JLabel Label_ElegirOpcion, Label_CantidadPeliculas;
    private JButton Boton_VerPeliculas, Boton_BuscarPelicula, Boton_AniadirPelicula, Boton_Exportar, Boton_Importar;
    private JButton Boton_Volver;
    private ArrayList<Pelicula> Peliculas;
    
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public Pantalla_MenuPeliculas() {

        this.Peliculas = new ArrayList<>();

        setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(580, 170);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Menu Peliculas");

        this.Label_ElegirOpcion = new JLabel("Elija una de las siguientes opciones:");
        this.Label_ElegirOpcion.setBounds(10, 10, 210, 30);
        add(this.Label_ElegirOpcion);

        this.Label_CantidadPeliculas = new JLabel("Cantidad de Peliculas: "+Peliculas.size()+".");
        this.Label_CantidadPeliculas.setBounds(380, 10, 210, 30);
        add(this.Label_CantidadPeliculas);

        this.Boton_VerPeliculas = new JButton("Ver todas las peliculas");
        this.Boton_VerPeliculas.setBounds(10, 50, 175, 30);
        add(this.Boton_VerPeliculas);
        this.Boton_VerPeliculas.addActionListener(this);

        this.Boton_BuscarPelicula = new JButton("Buscar pelicula");
        this.Boton_BuscarPelicula.setBounds(195, 50, 175, 30);
        add(this.Boton_BuscarPelicula);
        this.Boton_BuscarPelicula.addActionListener(this);

        this.Boton_AniadirPelicula = new JButton("Aniadir una pelicula");
        this.Boton_AniadirPelicula.setBounds(380, 50, 175, 30);
        add(this.Boton_AniadirPelicula);
        this.Boton_AniadirPelicula.addActionListener(this);

        this.Boton_Importar = new JButton("Importar Peliculas");
        this.Boton_Importar.setBounds(10, 90, 175, 30);
        add(this.Boton_Importar);
        this.Boton_Importar.addActionListener(this);

        this.Boton_Exportar = new JButton("Exportar Peliculas");
        this.Boton_Exportar.setBounds(195, 90, 175, 30);
        add(this.Boton_Exportar);
        this.Boton_Exportar.addActionListener(this);

        this.Boton_Volver = new JButton("Volver");
        this.Boton_Volver.setBounds(380, 90, 175, 30);
        add(this.Boton_Volver);
        this.Boton_Volver.addActionListener(this);

    }

    // OVERRIDE
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Evento) {
        if (Evento.getSource() == this.Boton_VerPeliculas){
            if (this.Peliculas.size() == 0){
                // MENSAJE DE IMPORTAR O AÑADIR PELICULAS
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Debe añadir o importar peliculas");
            }
            else{
                // MOSTRAR TODAS LAS PELICULAS
                dispose();
                new MenuPeliculas_MostrarPeliculas(this.Peliculas).setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        else if (Evento.getSource() == this.Boton_BuscarPelicula){
            if (this.Peliculas.size() == 0){
                // MENSAJE DE IMPORTAR O AÑADIR PELICULAS
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Debe añadir o importar peliculas");
            }
            else{
                // BUSCAR PELICULA
                dispose();
                new MenuPantalla_BuscarPelicula_IngresarTitulo(this.Peliculas).setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        else if (Evento.getSource() == this.Boton_AniadirPelicula){
            // AÑADIR PELICULA
            dispose();
            new MenuPeliculas_AniadirPelicula().setVisible(true);
        }
        else if (Evento.getSource() == this.Boton_Importar){
            // IMPORTAR PELICULAS
            //dispose();
            MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas Screen_1 = new MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas();
            //Screen_1.setVisible(true);
            this.Peliculas = Screen_1.getPeliculasImportadas();
            //this.Label_CantidadPeliculas = new JLabel("Cantidad de Peliculas: "+Peliculas.size()+".");
        }
        else if (Evento.getSource() == this.Boton_Exportar){
            if (this.Peliculas.size() == 0){
                // MENSAJE DE IMPORTAR O AÑADIR PELICULAS
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Debe añadir o importar peliculas");
            }
            else{
                // EXPORTAR PELICULAS
            }
        }
        else if (Evento.getSource() == this.Boton_Volver){
            dispose();
            new PantallaInicial().setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    
}
```

// CLASE MENUPELICULAS_IMPORTAR -------------------------------------------------------

```
public class MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    // ATRIBUTOS
    private JLabel Label_IngresarRuta;
    private JTextField CampoTexto_RutaArchivo;
    private JButton Boton_Importar, Boton_Volver;
    private ArrayList<Pelicula> PeliculasImportadas;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas(){

        this.PeliculasImportadas = new ArrayList<>();

        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(485, 170);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Importar Peliculas");

        this.Label_IngresarRuta = new JLabel("Ingrese la ruta absoluta del archivo de texto que quiere añadir.");
        this.Label_IngresarRuta.setBounds(10, 10, 450, 30);
        add(this.Label_IngresarRuta);

        this.CampoTexto_RutaArchivo = new JTextField();
        this.CampoTexto_RutaArchivo.setBounds(10, 50, 450, 30);
        add(this.CampoTexto_RutaArchivo);

        this.Boton_Importar = new JButton("Importar");
        this.Boton_Importar.setBounds(310, 90, 150, 30);
        add(this.Boton_Importar);
        this.Boton_Importar.addActionListener(this);

        this.Boton_Volver = new JButton("Volver");
        this.Boton_Volver.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 30);
        add(this.Boton_Volver);
        this.Boton_Volver.addActionListener(this);

    }

    // OVERRIDE
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Evento) {
        if (Evento.getSource() == this.Boton_Importar){
            if (this.CampoTexto_RutaArchivo.getText().isEmpty()){ // CAMPO DE TEXTO VACIO
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Debe escribir la ruta de un archivo de texto!");
            }
            else{ // CAMPO DE TEXTO LLENO
                if (verificarArchivo(this.CampoTexto_RutaArchivo.getText())){ // IMPORTAR
                    this.PeliculasImportadas = Importar_Peliculas(this.CampoTexto_RutaArchivo.getText());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha importado un total de: "+this.PeliculasImportadas.size()+" peliculas!");
                    // CERRAR Y RETORNAR INFORMACION
                }
                else{ // ERROR EN RUTA
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La ruta ingresada no es de un archivo de texto existente o legible!");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // TERMINAR
        }
    }

    // METODOS
    public boolean verificarArchivo(String Ruta_Archivo) {
        File archivo = new File(Ruta_Archivo);
        return ( archivo.exists() && archivo.canRead() );
    }
    public ArrayList<Pelicula> Importar_Peliculas(String _Ruta){
        FileReader Archivo;
        BufferedReader Lector;
        ArrayList<Pelicula> Peliculas_Importadas = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            Archivo = new FileReader(_Ruta);
            if (Archivo.ready()){
                Lector = new BufferedReader(Archivo);
                ArrayList<String> Leidos = new ArrayList<>();
                String Leido;
                Pelicula Nuevo;
                while ((Leido = Lector.readLine())!=null){
                    Leidos.add(Leido);
                }
                for(int i=0 ; i<Leidos.size() ; i=i+7){
                    Nuevo = new Pelicula(
                                Leidos.get(i),
                                Leidos.get(i+1),
                                Integer.parseInt(Leidos.get(i+2)),
                                Leidos.get(i+3),
                                Leidos.get(i+4),
                                Leidos.get(i+5),
                                Integer.parseInt(Leidos.get(i+6))
                                );
                    Peliculas_Importadas.add(Nuevo);
                }
                Lector.close();
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El archivo no esta listo para ser leido!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hubo un error durante la importacion del archivo.");
        }
        return Peliculas_Importadas;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public ArrayList<Pelicula> getPeliculasImportadas() {
        return PeliculasImportadas;
    }
}
```

Bueno nada, yo quiero que al abrir la ventana de importar, si se pudo completar el metodo Importar, que retorne el ArrayList, y en el MenuPeliculas añadirlo al ArrayList ya existente, y en caso de que se presione Volver, en la ventana de Importar, volver a la misma ventana MenuPeliculas que habia antes, sin perder la informacion.
Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Así como cachas los eventos de los botones, puedes cachar el evento cuando se oculta la pantalla de importación, implementando [ComponentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) en `Pantalla_MenuPeliculas` sin olvidar llamar a `JFrame.addComponentListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

yo optaría por pasarle al constructor de **MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas** el objeto de **Pantalla_MenuPeliculas**, algo así:

en la clase **Pantalla_MenuPeliculas**.

```
new MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas( this );
```

en **MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas**.

```
public class MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel Label_IngresarRuta;
    private JTextField CampoTexto_RutaArchivo;
    private JButton Boton_Importar, Boton_Volver;
    private ArrayList<Pelicula> PeliculasImportadas;
    Pantalla_MenuPeliculas pmp;

    public MenuPantalla_ImportarPeliculas( Pantalla_MenuPeliculas panMenPel ) {
        pmp = panMenPel;
        // etc..
```

cuando termina de hacer su tarea:

```
pmp.funcionQueHaceAlgo( listaQueDeboPasar );
```

en esta última linea. llamas a la función de **Pantalla_MenuPeliculas** que usará la lista en cuestión, y se la pasa como parámetro.